# Nextjs "use client" with React Containment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have a component that contains inside it (as children) content that needs to boost SEO. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
        <AnimatedElement className="flex flex-col justify-start items-center gap-4 w-full" duration={500}>
          <h2 className={montserratBoldFont.className + " font-bold text-4xl text-black text-left"}><span className='text-ac-violet'>Find</span> Us</h2>
          <Image src="/Homepage/hand-drawn-arrow.png" width={96} height={96} alt='' />
          <p className={latoFont.className + " font-medium text-sm xm:text-base leading-5 text-center text-white"}>
            {homepage.formations}
          </p>
        </AnimatedElement>
```

In the current page, I didn't put a `"use client"` directive, but inside the `AnimatedElement` component, I added `"use client"`.
So my question is wether or not the "children" are under the effect of `"use client"`?

Answer (score 0):

Children of `AnimatedElement` are client components, or are in effect of "use client" directive.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can use the server component in "use client" without it being "degraded" to a client component. You can find the corresponding explanation in the documentation.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#composing-client-and-server-components